Movie with creepy truck and dead bodies in white sheets
I saw a movie or part of it on TV a while ago. Maybe it was a show not sure. Mainly remember one scene and I'm not sure how accurate it is.
So it was about a girl and a guy they might have been a couple, and there might have been a 3rd person. But they were driving in a car (possibly red, at least thats how I remember it) on a long straight road in like a dessert area. Might have passes a couple cars but they were mainly by them selves. Then there was a grey truck behind them. It wasn't like a semi but like a ups one I think. 
They were going pretry fast but the truck was honking at them to go faster but they were signaling to pass them but the truck started to bump into them which made them run off the road. And the truck drove on. 
Then some time later the teensame or young adults in the car drove on as well but they were a little freaked out. Then they came by a abandoned looking house and saw the truck  by it. There was a guy in a long grey or neutral trench coat carrying something that was a body shaped thing wrapped in a white sheet. And then the guy throw it in to a well. The teens noticed it and they either stopped and waited to the guy to leave or they came back when he was gone. 
So they or one of them climbed down to see what he throw down and it was a dying bluish person. The bottom of the well was wide and had lots of other bodies in white sheets. That is all that I remember. Hopefully most of it is accurate. 

Hello @Ym48. You may need to add some questions to help keep this question from being put on hold. What year did you see it? What was the language? Can you estimate the year and country of production?

Why wo u ld it be put on hold when it was answered within 10 minutes of me posting?? Obviously it has enough info @John

You're describing a scene from Jeepers Creepers

A brother and sister driving home through isolated countryside for spring break encounter a flesh-eating creature which is on the last day of its ritualistic eating spree. 

Here's the scene






